# c# development, what type of files store resources (for localization)?

Tags: c#, .net

Where Visual Studio 2010 (using c#) stores the resources?  I need to monitor the files that stores resources in my product to know when I need a new translation. 
I have found this article that talks about it:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

According to that, all the files of type *.resx

I was wondering if there were any exceptions to that. In other words, it is possible that some resources would get stored in files with extension different from *.resx?

Thanks

-Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow recommended practice - yes all text resources are stored in resx files.

There are also other types of resources that may need to be localized - i.e. images may contain text/language specific content.

Note that if code does not strictly follow recommended practice some text that must be localized ends up in source code (i.e. format strings for String.Format calls).

Answer (score 2):

It actually tells you in the first paragraph in the the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you provided

> Visual C# applications often include data that is not source code.
>   Such data is referred to as a project resource and it can include
>   binary data, text files, audio or video files, string tables, icons,
>   images, XML files, or any other type of data that your application
>   requires. **Project resource data is stored in XML format in the .resx
>   file (named Resources.resx by default)** which can be opened in Solution
>   Explorer.

If you want to be sure you can always right-click on the file and select open with. This lets you choose a different editor to view the file in.